# Why does $\delta^i_j$ $\alpha^j$=$\alpha^i$?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am currently pursuing a self study in Tensor analysis and Tensor algebra and came across the following statement when exploring the Einstein summation convention:

Why does $\delta^i_j$$\alpha^j$=$\alpha^i$? (1)

My understanding of $\delta^1_j$$\alpha^j$=$\alpha^1$ (A similar example shown in my book) is
if we expand the left hand side of the equation we see that the only time $j=1$ is the first term in the sum, therefore we are left with $\alpha^1$. However, I am at a loss as to why the $\alpha$ is raised an $i$ on the right hand side of (1)? I am a beginner so I may be overlooking a simple explanation.

Comment: Expand the sum on the left hand side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implicit summation here as you mentioned:
$$ \sum_{j} \delta^i_j\alpha^j=\alpha^i$$
because 
$$ \delta^i_j=
\begin{cases}
1&i=j\\
0&i\ne j.
\end{cases}$$
So, in the sum when $i\ne j$, the term $\delta^i_j\alpha^j=0.$ In particular, the only nonzero summand is $\delta^i_i\alpha^i=\alpha^i$.

**Edit:** Also, thanks to the comment below I'll add the following:  in differential geometry (or anywhere tensors appear) some indices are written as superscripts: so, $\alpha^i$ is *not* $\alpha$ raised to the $i^{th}$ power, but rather it is simply an index.

Comment: Particularly the $i$ is not an exponent, it's an index just like $j$.

Comment: Ah yes, I should emphasize this.

Comment: @AEngineer so we are only interesred in the case when $i=j$?

Comment: That’s basically what the $\delta_^i_j$ signifies.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis gotcha. Since $i=j$, why can't the right side be $\alpha^j$? Is it because the free index must be the same on both sides of the equals?

Comment: $i$ is a chosen index, while $j$ is the index of summation. For instance, we might have $$ \sum_{j=1}^4 \delta^2_j \alpha^j=\alpha^2.$$
Here, $i=2$, and $j$ runs from $1\le j \le 4$.

Answer (score 0):

The $i$ in $\alpha^i$ is an *index* of a the vector $\alpha$, not an exponent. $\alpha^i$ is the $i$-th component of the vector $\alpha$, just like $\delta^a_b$ is the ${}^a_b$-th component of the tensor $\delta$. Specifically, $$\delta^a_b=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }A=b\\ 0&\text{if }a\ne b\end{cases}$$

So, like in the previous case, $$\delta^i_j\alpha^j:=\sum_{j=1}^n\delta^i_j\alpha^j=\alpha^i$$

because $\delta^i_i=1$ and all the other $\delta^i_j$-s are $0$.

Another interpretation of this is that $\delta^\bullet_j\alpha^j$ is the vector $\alpha$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation you need is that $\delta_j^i=1$ only when $j=i$ and is $0$ otherwise.Therefore $\delta_j^i\alpha^j=\alpha^i$, because the sum over $j$ has only $j=i$ as a non-zero term.